# sou novo no php e to confundindo muito qual a diferença desse sinal => pra esse ->

Tags: php

```
public function cadastro(Request $request)
{
 $user=new User();
 $user->name= $request->name;
 $user->email=$request->email;
 $user->password= FacadesHash::make($request->password);
 $user->save();
 return redirect()->route('users.listAll');
}


public function formEditUser(User $user){


    return view('editUser',[
        'user'=>$user


    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `=>` você está associando uma chave de um **array** com um valor. 
Com `->` você está acessando uma propriedade ou método de um **objeto**.

Eles não são similares, cada um tem um fim específico.